# How many ways you had used to decrease the Android apk size?

Tags: android, size, apk

as it said in title.
And which are them?
I think we can have a discuss here.
Thanks everybody!

Is there any hack way?such as part the resource.arsc file and then load the whole arsc from asset (I compressed it) when application create, or move the other language folder(zh_CN, jp) into asset so that i can compress it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cyril Mottier has a very good blog post about this: 
[Putting Your APKs on Diet](http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/08/26/putting-your-apks-on-diet/)

His post headlines:

Have a good coding hygiene

`...Get rid of all unused dependency libraries...projects with a large historical background usually have to deal with dead and/or almost useless code snippets.`

Run Proguard

`Proguard is an extremely powerful tool that obfuscates, optimizes and shrinks your code at compile time`

Use Lint extensively

`Proguard works on the Java side. Unfortunately, it doesn’t work on the resources side...[lint] generates an HTML-report and gives you the exhaustive list of resources that look unused under the “UnusedResources: Unused resources” section. It is safe to remove these resources`

Be opinionated about resources

`Android has been designed to support devices regardless of their configuration: screen density, screen shape, screen size, etc. As of Android 4.4, the framework natively supports various densities: ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi. Android supporting all these densities doesn’t mean you have to export your assets in each one of them.`

Minimize resources configurations

`Android development often relies on the use of external libraries such as Android Support Library, Google Play Services, Facebook SDK, etc. All of theses libraries comes with resources that are not necessary useful to your application. For instance, Google Play Services comes with translations for languages your own application don’t even support.`

Compress images

`A quick Google search yields several tools such as pngquant, ImageAlpha or ImageOptim. Just pick the one that best fits your designer workflow and requirements and use it!`

I want to add a very useful online service: [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/)

Limit the number of architectures

`Android is generally about Java but there are some rare cases where applications need to rely on some native code...Sticking to armabi and x86 architecture is usually enough in the current Android eco-system.`

Reuse whenever possible

`For instance, Android provides several utilities to re-color an asset either using the new android:tint and android:tintMode on Android L or the good old ColorFilter on all versions.`

or

`You can also prevent packaging resources that are only a rotated equivalent of another resource.`

Render in code when appropriate

`In some cases rendering graphics directly for the Java code can have a great benefit. One of the best example of a mammoth weight gain is with frame-by-frame animations.`

Comment: Thank you very much.I study a lot from this blog!

Answer (score 1):

Remove unnecessary resource (images, etc). This is the most effective method. Then remove unnecessary classes and libraries.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways but at the end all are same, because its related with **Unnecessary** things.

You just need to remove Unnecessary Resources, classes, libraries.

I can say we have 5 folders to put one image in all the folders with different sizes, so I suggest you to prefer **9 patch image** instead of 5 different images (whenever you can put). Using this way you can reduce your apk size most effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling ProGuard, even without obfuscation. It will remove unused Java code from your dependencies.
See if you have unneeded dependencies - JARs that you've added but aren't using
Check your resources for large images or other files. You may want to change their format or resolution, or remove them if they're not in use.
you compress the .jpg files as much as possible, this should greatly reduce the size of your .apk file. A tool such as Paint.NET which is free should help you do this. It has great resizing options.